# <asp:Button> not work properly : the action effect not run every once i press the button with my simple search?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have long table with a lot of cells 
i make simple to find the specific cell and make it's background yellow like highlighting 
The code is ok but when i press the search button once go to the searched cell and once after 2 times go to the searched cell .. i don't know what affect on the button action

the code is long i was hope to attach it but i will cope it here in the following:

// *********** my asp
http://www.mediafire.com/file/hsgvjgv838gffq5/Compaines.aspx

// *********** the c# file
http://www.mediafire.com/file/w980kd4desbaxd7/Compaines.aspx.cs

I hope any one can solve give me why that happen

Comment: Are you trying to scroll the page to the highlighted cell?  Is the search button already highlighting the appropriate cells?  Not sure that the problem is

Comment: Does it work when you click the button twice? I did have a bug where I had to press the button twice in order for it to register the click.

Answer (score 0):

I've had asp button posting issues in grids before, just for kicks, replace it with a linkbutton and see if it works...